# How to forecast a Macro trend by multiple Index time-series Using LSTM Model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-transformation, lstm, feature-engineering

I am new in machine learning and I found that lots of article only train the `LSTM model` by only one stock and do the `forecast`. As a result, I am trying to group multiple Index and then predict an overall market trend to see what would happen. Therefore, I would like to know whether the below approach is correct.

```
Sample data - close price of multiple Index
                    ^DJI        ^GSPC        ^IXIC         ^RUT
Date                                                           
2017-01-03  19881.759766  2257.830078  5429.080078  1365.489990
2017-01-04  19942.160156  2270.750000  5477.000000  1387.949951
2017-01-05  19899.289062  2269.000000  5487.939941  1371.939941
2017-01-06  19963.800781  2276.979980  5521.060059  1367.280029
2017-01-09  19887.380859  2268.899902  5531.819824  1357.489990
```

For the feature engineering part, I have below 2 approaches:

1. Take the average of the above 4 Index Close price. And add one column to hold the shifted data
   [image: avg]
2. Keep the 4 Index Close price and add one column at the end to hold the shifted data of "DJI" (one of the Index) for supervision training.
   [image: dji]

So, I would like to know which one is a better approach or other ways for `featuring data` are welcome since I am still learning it. Long way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about feature selection/engineering, and this is a (the) major part of ML. While, for a very long time, people have put a lot of thinking into feature engineering, in recent years the trend has become to not worry too much about finding the best features and rather let the machine do this work. Models that are used with the latter approach are e.g. random forest, gradient boosting machines, and, of course, deep neural networks (DNNs). This works as long as you have enough data, and those "data-driven" approaches need quite a lot of data.

So, since you are using LSTMs, i.e. DNNs, you should not have to put much effort into designing good features, just hand all your data to the DNN. Make sure it gets the maximum information. That means, definitely favor the second approach. In case the average (the feature that is used in the first approach) is indeed the best and only necessary feature to use, in the second approach the LSTM should figure that out itself.

Of course, it probably is not much more work to also use the first approach and then compare it with the second. That could give you some insight into your data, and whether you should continue tuning your second approach.

In case you don't have sufficient data, it is better to go for the classic models, like time series models (ARIMA, VAR, Kalman, ...) which also have the great advantage of being much more interpretable and often revealing new information about your data generating process.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation! One more question, for the second approach, when there are 4 Index as my case, would it be weird if I only choose one of them and do shifting to be the supervised feature? I get your point that LSTM will handle them but is there any better way to handle the supervised column by ourselves?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: What do you mean by "handle the supervised column"?

Comment: I see there is common practice to add one more column at the end of the data which holding e.g. "DJI index" price but shifted 2 days as my approach 2 shown. I guess that column is guiding the model to train?

Comment: @WILLIAM I understood your post such that the last column would be what you want to predict (you wrote: "for supervision training"). In general the idea is to have some input to the ML algorithm, the features or "independent variables" (IVs), and the output or "dependent variable" (DV), and we want to learn a function that maps the IVs to the DV such that, after the training, we can use this learned algorithm to obtain predictions of the DV for new values of the IVs. You could, of course, also change the DV into a vector containing more then one variable, if that was your question.